# Duda sobre float y int

Tags: python, python-2.7, float

Tengo un programa que me lee datos de archivos `excel` y `csv` y los escribe en un `txt`.
El problema que tengo es que una de las columnas que lee son decimales y al escribírmelos los pone todos como decimal. El tema es que yo solo quiero que me escriba como decimal los que sean diferentes de 0; mientras que si el decimal es 0, quiero que lo escriba como un entero.

Por ejemplo:

```
si el dato que lee es: 3.1    
quiero que escriba: 3.1    
pero si el dato que lee es: 3.0    
quiero que escriba: 3*
```

Pongo parte del código:

```
#Leo los datos y los almaceno en una lista
hoja = miExcel.sheet_by_index(0)
for row in range(1, hoja.nrows, 1):
    dato = hoja.cell_value(row, 2)
    listaDatos.append(pInstEol)
#Escribo los datos fila a fila iterando por indice
with open(ficheroTxt, 'w') as f:
    for indiceXls, nombreDato in enumerate (listaNombreDato):
        dato = listaDatos[indiceXls]
        f.write(str(dato) + ... + '\n')
```

Espero haberme explicado bien.
Cómo puedo hacerlo, porque o todos `float` o todos `int`. No sé hacer esa excepción.
Gracias

Comment: En lugar de `str(dato)` coloca `('%g' % dato)` y me cuentas.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciona perfectamente. 
Ya por aprender un poco más, ¿qué es exactamente lo que hace el %g y el % dato? Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para eso puedes darle formato a tu cadena de texto (`dato`) con String Formatting Operations.

Así:

```
f.write(('%g' % dato) + ... + '\n')
```

Si miras segmento `'%g' % dato` está compuesto por 3 cosas:

- `'%g'` (formato a utilizar)
- `%` (operador para ejecutar el formato)
- `dato` (string al cual vamos a formatear)

Puedes encontrar la utilidad del formato `'%g'` y de muchos más en la documentación oficial de python:

[link](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html)

Saludos.